# Implementing callback in Realm and set it in presenter MVP for async work

Tags: android, realm, android-mvp

In the first problem my way was loading async data, and when I completed 1 method from the presenter, I called second method, but my data is still loaded at this point. Well, after that I resolved this problem, and I need to set some callbacks to realm methods to be sure that my data is loaded and after the download I need to get it from the database and reflect in the view. But I have some problems with the implementation interface. What is the best way to do this? I will try to write the code below:

In my presenter:

```
getViewState().showListProgress();
    repository.loadDataFromNetworkToDB();

    List<Anime> animeList = repository.loadDataFromDbToPresenter();
    if (animeList.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("you are loosing!S");
        Throwable error = new Throwable();
        onLoadingFailed(error);
    } else {
        onLoadingFinish();
        onLoadingSuccess(animeList);
    }
```

My base function to save data into Realm:

```
public void saveToDatabase(final OnTransactionCallback onTransactionCall) {
    try {

        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                for (Anime a : animeList) {
                    Anime anime = new Anime();
                    anime.setFromEntity(a);
                    System.out.println("title: " + anime.getTitle() + " saveToDb: ");
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(anime);
                }
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                if (onTransactionCall != null) {
                    onTransactionCall.onRealmSuccess();
                }
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                if (onTransactionCall != null) {
                    onTransactionCall.onRealmError();
                }
            }
        });
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}

public interface OnTransactionCallback {
    boolean onRealmSuccess();

    boolean onRealmError();
}
```

After it, I download data from network and used two functions in the model:

```
public void loadDataFromNetworkToDB() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    ghibliService.getAnimeList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(list -> {
                AnimeDbHelper dbHelper = new AnimeDbHelper(realm, list);
                dbHelper.saveToDatabase(this);
            });
}

@Override
public List<Anime> loadDataFromDbToPresenter() {
    List<Anime> animeList = new ArrayList<>();
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    try {
        final RealmResults<Anime> animeResults = realm.where(Anime.class).findAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < animeResults.size(); i++) {
            animeList.add(animeResults.get(i).toEntity());
        }
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
    return animeList;

}

@Override
public boolean onRealmSuccess() {
    System.out.println("Success");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onRealmError() {
    System.out.println("Error");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `and after the download I need to get it from the database and reflect in the view.` why don't you use LiveData?

Comment: How can I solve the problem using LiveData? It's just watching the data, and after calling repository.loadDataFromDbToPresenter (), I get the size 0. Should I repeat it in a loop until I get some data?

Comment: you don't need to reload data in `onTransactionCall.onRealmSuccess();` if you use a `RealmChangeListener` added to the `RealmResults` (and the RealmResults is kept as field reference)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this code below resolve my problem but after I get updated list objects I catch exceptions like this:

```
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5614(449KB) AllocSpace objects, 18(288KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 1691KB/2MB, paused 5.354ms total 10.731ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7039(557KB) AllocSpace objects, 22(352KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 1561KB/2MB, paused 10.554ms total 15.931ms
```

Apparently, the presenter should have his own life cycle, and somewhere we need to delete liveData.
In my model:

```
public RealmLiveData<Anime> findAnimes() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmLiveData<Anime> realmLiveData;
    try {
        realmLiveData = new RealmLiveData<>(realm.where(Anime.class).findAllAsync());
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
    return realmLiveData;
}
```

In my presenter:

```
@Override
public void loadData() {
    view.onDataStarted();

    repository.getAnimeFromNetwork();

    liveData = repository.findAnimes();

    liveData.observeForever(new Observer<RealmResults<Anime>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable RealmResults<Anime> animes) {
            if (animes != null) {
                if (animes.size() == 0) {
                    //nothing
                    System.out.println("Result realmResult: " + animes.size());
                } else {
                    view.onDataCompleted();
                    System.out.println("My result before Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC: " + animes.size());
                    List<Anime> animeList = new ArrayList<>();
                    animeList.addAll(animes);
                    view.showData(animeList);
                    //Trying to stop liveData - helplessness
                    liveData.removeObserver(this::onChanged);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("null" + animes);
            }
        }
    });
```

RealmLiveData:

```
public class RealmLiveData<T extends RealmModel> extends LiveData<RealmResults<T>> {
private RealmResults<T> results;
private final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> listener =
        new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmResults<T> results) {
                setValue(results);
            }
        };
public RealmLiveData(RealmResults<T> realmResults) {
    results = realmResults;
}
@Override
protected void onActive() {
    results.addChangeListener(listener);
}
@Override
protected void onInactive() {
    results.removeChangeListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you use `observeForever` and remove the observer in the observer, instead of using it as originally intended: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata (subscribe in onCreateView, remove observers in onDestroyView)?

Comment: Because I used another library, where the state of presenter is save when the activity is rotated etc. So, I need to refuse this path and extends from ViewModel and use some arhitecture components from google.

Comment: Honestly I was just referring to using `observe(lifecycleOwner, { ...` and relying on automatic unsubscription

Comment: This answer was helpful to put me on the right track for my solution.